# Development workflow with pixi.js and browserify (Error: browserify can't find pixi.js module)

Tags: javascript, browserify, pixi.js

I started to test pixi.js and followed this tutorial http://frontender.info/introduction-to-pixijs/ (sorry It's in Russian, but you can translate it with google translate). I liked workflow of this tutorial, I need to use "require" in browser, and I need quckly test game in browser. Everything works fine, but when I request beefy server on url http://localhost:9966/ I am getting error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'pixi.js' from 'C:\Users\PainKiller\Desktop\pixitest'
at C:\Users\PainKiller\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:46:17
at process (C:\Users\PainKiller\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:173:43)
at ondir (C:\Users\PainKiller\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:188:17)
at load (C:\Users\PainKiller\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:69:43)
at onex (C:\Users\PainKiller\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:92:31)
at C:\Users\PainKiller\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:22:47
at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
```

What I've tried:
1. Installed pixi.js with different commands.
2. Manually put file pixi.js in C:\Users\PainKiller\Desktop\pixitest\node_modules\pixi.js folder (after running all that install commands there was no pixi.js file)
3. Put index.html in the root of the folder with:

```
<!doctype html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Hello World</title>
<body>
<script src="http://pixijs.download/release/pixi.js"></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>
<script>

//Test that Pixi is working
console.log(PIXI);

</script>
</body>
```

When I add link to my index.js file error shows again.
My current OS Windows 10, if it can help.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Some additional info.
When I run

```
browserify index.js -o bundle.js
```

in the root folder of my project I am getting the same error. But pixi.js file located in node_modules/pixi.js folder, why browserify can't find it???

EDIT2:
When I put pixi.js in folder, use require in this way:

```
var PIXI = require('./node_modules/pixi.js/pixi.js');
```

browserify find it, but it gives another error:

```
 Error: Cannot find module './GLTexture' from 'C:\Users\PainKiller\Desktop\pixite
st\node_modules\pixi.js'
```

Comment: Install pixi.js [using NPM](https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js#npm-install)

Comment: I did it. Do you read the post?

Comment: You should never need relative or absolute paths with npm installed packages, so:
npm i pixi.js
and you should be able to use just:
var PIXI = require('pixi.js');
if npm is correctly installed, meaning that it should automatically have a path to the node_modules folder.

I use webpack myself and it works with npm i pixi.js and requiring (or in my case importing using ES6) fine.

It is working for me e.g. here: https://github.com/Hachitus/FlaTWorld/blob/master/src/core/Flatworld.js

Comment: Thanks for comment, you're developing very nice library, but I did var PIXI = require('pixi.js') and get error, and only then I've started experiment with paths.

Answer (score 0):

Still don't know if browserify works with pixi.js as npm module, some issues on github repo says that it was fixed in newer version of pixi.js. But anyway if you met this problem you can switch to webpack (and I did it), or use pixi.js as global import (via script tag).